# Best way to include pagination in a theme

Tags: themes, pagination

I'd like to develop pagination into my theme, FluX, as well as some other things, which I'll outline soon on GitHub. But pagination for my articles template is really high on the list. Can anyone tell me the best way to go about this? It needs to be number-based with buttons for previous and next, and work with the current loop I use (a foreach loop instead of "the loop")

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: I looked at that but that is made for use with The Loop, not with my custom foreach loop.

Comment: Why are you not using the loop?

Comment: Because my foreach loop seems to be faster, though I am switching back now.

Answer (score 1):

Paginations mostly rely on the global `$wp_query` variable to generate the data. Using  `get_posts()` will not generate that, because it returns an array of posts, not an instance of the `WP_Query()` class itself. As a result, you don't have access to class's methods, such as `$query->max_num_pages`.

You can use a plugin to add pagination (such as [WP-PageNavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) by Lester Chan) which supports custom queries, or you can write your own.

Here is a piece of code that will create a simple pagination for your queries. But notice, you have to use `WP_Query()`, not `get_posts()`:

```
function get_pagination( $query = null ) {
    if( is_singular() )
        return;
    // Check if any custom query is passed to the function
    if ($query == null ) {
        global $wp_query;
    } else {
        $wp_query = $query;
    }
    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );
    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;
    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }
    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }
    echo '<div class="photogram-navigation">' . "\n";
    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );
    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );
        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>...</li>';
    }
    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }
    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>...</li>' . "\n";
        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }
    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );
    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
}
```

Now you can output your pagination by using `get_pagination()` in your archives, or by using `get_pagination( $my_query )` and using it anywhere you wish ( `$my_query` is your custom query).

Answer (score 0):

Most of pagination logic in core naturally deals with native data structures, such as post loops, comments, and so on.

There is a low level [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) functions, which allows you to construct arbitrary pagination logic. However you will be on your own with a lot of remaining stuff, such as query variables, rewrite, and so on.